# LED always on while using FET

Tags: electronics, mosfet

I want to switch on/off some LEDs on a breadboard using my Raspberry PI (RPi) 4. Before connecting with my RPi, I've tried to do some experiments with using a BS270 FET in an old-fashioned "dumb" circuit.

Layout is a simple serial circut:

```
3V source (2 AA batteries) +
100 ohm resistor
LED
BS270 FET (D leg connected to LED, G leg not connected to anything, S leg to battery -)
(batteries - / cathode)
```

So it forms a circuit. I switch it on, and the LED shines. Problem is it always shines, as if the BS270 FET conducts current regardless of what I do with the G-leg.

As I understand it the BS270 should only conduct current if the G leg has voltage applied to it, like 3V. Seems like it doesn't matter if it has voltage or not. I'm doing something wrong, but I am not knowledgeable enough to understand where to look.

**Update**

I eventually got it to work with several GPIOs each toggling on/off their own transistor. This is the circuit I built for each. Apologies for any drawing errors (I'm an amateur):
[image: GPIO used to switch BS270 transistor on and off]

Comment: please draw a schematic diagram

Comment: My apologies. I will draw schematics for future questions.

Comment: Have you connected and tested the FET with your Raspberry Pi yet?

Comment: I tried, but found I know too little at the present :) I need to study FETs a bit more. Maybe a BJT is easier to get working?

Comment: I finally got it working the other day. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause for BS270 (or any n-channel JFET) to continue conducting is, as you said, `"G leg not connected to anything"`. The capacitance in the Gate junction stores a charge created when you turned the LED "ON". You should be able to drain the charge by connecting a resistor between the Gate junction and Ground - as shown in the schematic below. Once drained, the JFET will turn OFF - and so will the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI9A02.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That worked perfectly! Now I can consistently close and open the circuit by manually placing a resistor so G either gets a voltage, or is drained like you wrote.

Comment: ICYI: Not part of the question, but putting this in a "RPi GPIO" context: In addition to adding a discrete resistor as shown above, it's also possible to add an internal pulldown to the driving GPIO pin via software - [for example](https://grantwinney.com/using-pullup-and-pulldown-resistors-on-the-raspberry-pi/). In this case, a GPIO pin takes the place of V2, SW1 and R1 in the schematic above.